# React Native laravel echo listen is not working

Tags: laravel, react-native, socket.io, real-time, laravel-echo

Everything works just fine with laravel redis and everything running and working with no issues. However, I am not getting a console log for my event from react native and there is no warnings or errors. Here is my code

App.js

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo/dist/echo';
import Socketio from 'socket.io-client';

const echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'socket.io',
    host: 'http://localhost:6001',
    client: Socketio,
    auth: {
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Bearer 7ebee00f74965d11cae413998a13c802',
      },
    },
  });

  let orderId = 9;

  echo.channel('app_database_order.' + orderId)
    .listen('.OrderStatusEvent', (e) => {
      console.log('event: ', e);
    });
```

and this is my Laravel echo server console

```
⚠ Starting server in DEV mode...

✔  Running at localhost on port 6001
✔  Channels are ready.
✔  Listening for http events...
✔  Listening for redis events...

Server ready!

Channel: app_database_order.9
Event: OrderStatusEvent
Channel: app_database_order.9
Event: OrderStatusEvent
Channel: app_database_order.9
Event: OrderStatusEvent
```

laravel-echo-server.json:

```
{
    "authHost": "http://localhost",
    "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
    "clients": [
        {
            "appId": "AppId",
            "key": "7ebee00f74965d11cae413998a13c802"
        }
    ],
    "database": "redis",
    "databaseConfig": {
        "redis": {
            "port":"6379",
            "host":"127.0.0.1",
            "db":"0",
            "password":"0TaEotyBIzOSym6zEXdsD2f2VCiPJmj4s/2nkGgyC4BBnm7CVUphOPCJ3LYoEUWuuqLokqJ/CCrJ3HqR"
        },
        "sqlite": {
            "databasePath": "/database/laravel-echo-server.sqlite"
        },
        "publishPresence": true
    },
    "devMode": true,
    "host": null,
    "port": "6001",
    "protocol": "http",
    "socketio": {},
    "secureOptions": 67108864,
    "sslCertPath": "",
    "sslKeyPath": "",
    "sslCertChainPath": "",
    "sslPassphrase": "",
    "subscribers": {
        "http": true,
        "redis": true
    },
    "apiOriginAllow": {
        "allowCors": true,
        "allowOrigin": "*",
        "allowMethods": "GET, POST",
        "allowHeaders": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token, X-Requested-With, Accept, Authorization, X-CSRF-TOKEN, X-Socket-Id"
    }
}
```

And I am trying to trigger the event by calling this API from postman:

```
Route::post('/ship', function (Request $request)
{
    $order_id = $request->input('order_id');

    $order = Order::findOrFail($order_id);
    event(new OrderStatus($order));
    return true;
});
```

Order Status Event:

```
class OrderStatus implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $order_id;

    public function __construct(Order $order)
    {
        $this->order_id = $order->id;
    }

    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('order.'.$this->order_id);
    }

    public function broadcastAs() {
        return 'OrderStatusEvent';
    }
}
```

I am using expo to run react-native, so the log should appear in the expo console,
and nothing appears.

I am working on this problem for 3 days with no solutions :(.
Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Try downgrading to Echo version 2.4.0. It solved the problem for me.

Also, in place of `echo.listen()` use `echo.on()`

Answer (score 0):

friend use this code in react native :

```js
import {Text, AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import Pusher from "pusher-js/react-native";
//import Pusher from 'pusher-js' no es compatible con react native  ya que react native no tiene elementos html DOM
import Echo from 'laravel-echo'

const connectToWebSocket = async () => {
    
      try {
        const ws = new Echo({
          broadcaster: "pusher",
          Pusher, // sets the instance imported above

          // Tweak the options according to your settings
          key: "app-key", // set the key defined in your .env
          wsHost: "192.168.1.4", // the host defined in your .env
          wssHost: "192.168.1.4", // the host defined in your .env
          wsPort: 6001, // or the port defined in your .env
          wssPort: 6001, // or the port defined in your .env
          forceTLS: false,
          encrypted: false,
          cluster: "mt1",
          enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
        });

        console.log(ws);
        const channel = ws.channel('test-event');
        channel.subscribed( () => {
          console.log('subscribed');
      
      }).listen('.test-event', (e) => {
         console.log("Escuchando Evento :",e);
      });
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("error", error);
      }
    };

    // Llama a la función para conectarte al servidor WebSocket local
    connectToWebSocket();
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).