# laravel echo event listening on react native mobile app

Tags: javascript, laravel, react-native, socket.io, laravel-echo

I am working on a react native mobile app with laravel backend, using laravel echo , socket.io , redis on my webserver, which is working fine in the website. But when i try to listen the same event in my react native app, it does not show anything in console.

In my react native app i am using laravel echo and socket.io.

Here is my react native app.js file looks like

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import Echo from 'laravel-echo/dist/echo';
import socketio from 'socket.io-client';

class App extends Component {
 constructor(props) {
super(props);
let echo = new Echo({
  broadcaster: 'socket.io',
  host: 'http://127.0.0.1:6001',
  client: socketio,
});

echo
  .channel('laravel_database_public-channel')
  .listen('.MessageEvent', event => {
    //Handling event
    console.log('****', event);
  });

console.log('############', echo);
}

 render() {
return <Text>ABCDEFGHIJKL</Text>;
}
}

export default App;
```

Logging echo:

```
console.log(echo);
```

Result:

```
Echo {
"connector": SocketIoConnector {
"_defaultOptions": Object {
  "auth": Object {
    "headers": Object {},
  },
  "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
  "broadcaster": "socket.io",
  "client": [Function lookup],
  "csrfToken": null,
  "host": "http://127.0.0.1:6001",
  "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
  "key": null,
  "namespace": "App.Events",
  "path": "/socket.io",
  "port": "6001",
  "secure": false,
},
"channels": Object {
  "laravel_database_public-channel": SocketIoChannel {
    "eventFormatter": EventFormatter {
      "namespace": "App.Events",
    },
    "events": Object {
      "MessageEvent": Array [
        [Function listener],
      ],
      "reconnect": Array [
        [Function listener],
      ],
    },
    "name": "laravel_database_public-channel",
    "options": Object {
      "auth": Object {
        "headers": Object {},
      },
      "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
      "broadcaster": "socket.io",
      "client": [Function lookup],
      "csrfToken": null,
      "host": "http://127.0.0.1:6001",
      "hostname": "127.0.0.1",
      "key": null,
      "namespace": "App.Events",
      "path": "/socket.io",
      "port": "6001",
      "secure": false,
    },
    "socket": Socket {
      "_callbacks": Object {
        "$MessageEvent": Array [
          [Function listener],
        ],
        "$connect": Array [
          [Function anonymous],
        ],
        "$connecting": Array [
          [Function onConnecting],
        ],
        "$reconnect": Array [
          [Function listener],
        ],
      },
```

I get the details of my channel and event when i log it after declaring the channel.

I also tried to listen on node js and react js web application and it works fine.
but on react native client it dones not show any thing in console. I tested out many possible changes in configuration.
Also test out on React native CLI and EXPO but same no response.

Please guide what seems to be the isses.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Your echo server also outputs to when connections get authorized and messages sent. Does is show anything? Also check not only your console, also your network activity. Any websocket errors?

Comment: @MaartenVeerman How can i check network activity on react native expo?

Comment: Checkout one of the solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70681250/17914265